# How can I get files from the iDisk programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I need to write an iPhone app that allows the user to download and use files (more specifiably, video files) that are on the Mobile Me iDisk. Is this possible? I was not able to find an iDisk API for Objective-C.

Comment: Are you able to connect to an iDisk via FTP? I seem to remember this being possible (though, it may not be suitable for what you want to do).

Comment: Is this for use on a computer or an iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into compiling [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) as a static library for the iPhone. That would give you the means to access WebDAV resources.

Answer (score 2):

iDisk supports [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), which is a file access and versioning protocol based on HTTP.  WebDAV is the basis for the iDisk integration with Windows -  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3264.